# What is the MagickWand equivalent of the "-colors" option?

Tags: imagemagick, magickwand

I have several images that I'm processing with ImageMagick.  In this case, I'm converting an RGBA PNG into an indexed PNG.  If I use the `convert` tool, I have reasonable control over the number of colors in the indexed PNG:

```
$ convert infile.png -colors 128 outfile.png
$ identify outfile.png
outfile.png PNG 77x77 77x77+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 91c 3.03KiB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

It seems to reduce the color count substantially (91 < 128) I am trying to do the same conversion with MagickWand's `MagickQuantizeImage(wand, 128, RGBColorspace, tree_depth=1, 0, 0)`.  The signature of the function is

```
MagickBooleanType MagickQuantizeImage(
              MagickWand       *wand,
        const size_t            number_colors,
              ColorspaceType    colorspace,
        const size_t            treedepth,
        const MagickBooleanType dither,
        const MagickBooleanType measure_error)
```

The end result is an image with too few colors (only 11!):

```
$ identify wandoutfile.png
wandoutfile.png PNG 77x77 77x77+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 11c 1.31KiB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish a reduction of colors using MagickWand (without destroying the image in the process?)

Thanks!

Comment: No.  I wrapped the call to convert in a nice class and went on with life.

Answer (score 1):

Use `treedepth=8, measure_error=1`.   See [the documentation for details](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-image.php?ImageMagick=s75kt9vbdb2h4klf40ouav2j10#MagickQuantizeImage).

You might also consider using the YIQ colorspace as suggested [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#quantize).